# node.js async juggling learnyounode tutorial

Tags: node.js

I am going through the learnyounode tutorials and have got stuck on the juggling async one. I have head a search through solutions online and my code appears to be the same!! I am using windows cmd.

It says syntax error: unexpected token ) after the i++... I'm really confused. Not sure how it is an error?

```
var http = require('http');
var bl = require('bl');
var results = [];
var counter = 0;


function print(){
    for (var i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
        console.log(results[i])
    }
}

function gethttp (idx) {

http.get(process.argv[2 + index], function(response){
    response.pipe(bl(function(err,data){
        if (err)
        {
            return console.error(err)
        }
            results[idx] = data.toString()
            counter++

            if (counter == 3)
                print()
                }))
})
}
      for (var i = 0; i < 3, i++)
      {
          gethttp(i)
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a comma instead of a semicolon in the last 'for' loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3, i++)
  {
      gethttp(i)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The for loop below has syntax error (comma instead of semicolon):

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 3, i++)
  {
      gethttp(i)
  }
```

Should be:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
  {
      gethttp(i)
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var http = require('http');

var links = [2, 3, 4];

var buffer = [];

(function render(index) {

    http.get(process.argv[links[index]], function (response){

        response.setEncoding('utf8');

        response.on('data', function(chunk){
            if(buffer[index] === undefined) {
                buffer[index] = '';
            }
            buffer[index] += chunk;
        });
        response.on('end', function () {
            var newIndex = index+1;
            if(links[newIndex] !== undefined) {
                render(newIndex);
            } else {
                return renderOutput();
            }
        });
        response.on('error', console.error);

    }).on('error', console.error);
})(0); //self-calling function

function renderOutput() {

buffer.forEach(function (elem) {

 console.log(elem);

    });

}
```